# Redirecting non www domain to www domain except https

Tags: .htaccess, http-redirect, redirect

i have a domain which which is like www.mydomain.com

and i want to redirect all non www request requests to www except for https requests.

i am using this one, which is redirecting all requests to www

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

what i want to do is, preventing redirects of requests like https://sslsites.com/mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

Add the following (before the RewriteRule):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

Apache mod_rewrite documentation is available [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: didn't work for me:/ is there any way to redirect like, rewrite all domains, except if 'https://sslsites.com' comes before?

Comment: You could try `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443`.